# NSURLCache crashes under iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, ios6, nsurlcache

Using iOS 6.1 my App crashes regulary, directly after startup, when it attempts to make several HTTP-Requests, but it works fine on any OS < 6.1.

I'm experiencing 
`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crashes in the `strlen` function called from the Queue : `com.apple.CFURLCACHE_work_queue`, everytime my App is started, except for the first time.

[image: NSURLCache crashes]

I could resolve the issue by clearing the NSURLCache, directly after the app started:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

Does anyone else experience these crashes? Could there be some issue in the application code causing these crashes? Or should this be a bug filed to apple?

Comment: Possibly related to a severe iOS 6.1 bug reported yesterday, when it connects to (and crashes) Microsoft Exchange servers?

Comment: It seems like this has been fixed on iOS8, our crash reporting tool only reports this on iOS7

Answer (score 1):

Experiencing a similar crash since iOS 6.1 with a newly installed application. The difference is that the crash occurs when tapping a text cell in a table view. No web requests are being made at this time.

This is the bt:

```
thread #4: tid = 0x2903, 0x3ae7ad74 libsystem_c.dylib`strlen + 28, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
frame #0: 0x3ae7ad74 libsystem_c.dylib`strlen + 28
frame #1: 0x3ac6be24 libsqlite3.dylib`___lldb_unnamed_function282$$libsqlite3.dylib + 1232
frame #2: 0x3ac74a5e libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3_file_control + 174
frame #3: 0x328493fe CFNetwork`__CFURLCache::RecreateEmptyPersistentStoreOnDiskAndOpen_NoLock() + 30
frame #4: 0x32849000 CFNetwork`__CFURLCache::RecreateEmptyPersistentStoreOnDiskAndOpen() + 44
frame #5: 0x327f9488 CFNetwork`__CFURLCache::OpenDatabase() + 192
frame #6: 0x32846a72 CFNetwork`__CFURLCache::ProcessCacheTasks0(bool) + 358
frame #7: 0x32846900 CFNetwork`__CFURLCache::ProcessCacheTasks(bool) + 36
frame #8: 0x3284681e CFNetwork`__CFURLCache::_CFURLCacheTimerCallback0() + 358
frame #9: 0x328466ac CFNetwork`__CFURLCache::_CFURLCacheTimerCallback(void*) + 32
frame #10: 0x328490fc CFNetwork`__SignalWorkerTaskToPerformWork_block_invoke_0 + 12
frame #11: 0x3ae4611e libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
frame #12: 0x3ae49ece libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 142
frame #13: 0x3ae49dc0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 40
frame #14: 0x3ae4a91c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 184
frame #15: 0x3ae4aac0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 84
frame #16: 0x3ae7aa10 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 360
frame #17: 0x3ae7a8a4 libsystem_c.dylib`start_wqthread + 8
```

Reported this as a TSI to Apple, it was reviewed and they requests that I log this as a bug, still need to do this.

Interestingly enough the solution which you found also helped me, clearing the cache at launch solved this problem.

Comment: My BT looked pretty similar, crashing code was called from RecreateEmptyPersistentStoreOnDiskAndOpen_NoLock(), too.

Can you only reproduce the crash by tapping the cell? Or does the app possibly crash after a certain time and its only a coincidence?

Comment: The app can be crashed with the same BT by tapping any cell on any xib. We can reproduce this on any device as long as it runs iOS 6.1 and the app is installed from scratch. 

When leaving it running idle no crash occurs.

Comment: Please file this bug with Apple!  Noting the cache clearing as a fix seems like it should help them figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is only half an answer, but I'm running into a very similar problem whilst running my unit tests. Bizarrely, this only seemed to start happening today.

The full details of my issue are outlined in [this Apple dev forums thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/797625#797625).

The common link between our problems appears to be the call to `RecreateEmptyPersistentStoreOnDiskAndOpen_NoLock()`. If my understanding of CFURLCache is correct, and based on the backtrace, it uses a sqlite3 database internally as a cache. I'd assume this function call creates the empty sqlite3 database on disk.

I was able to repeatedly and consistently stop my tests crashing by deleting the simulator's Library/Caches directory (`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Library/Caches`) and make the crash return by re-creating that directory.

Deleting the entire simulator home directory and letting it be recreated by launching my app in the simulator would also fix and re-create the issue.

I'm guessing this is an OS bug; the curious thing is why for me, it only just started happening.